# Python Install enigma-catalyst but errored out. " Feature ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature'"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, setuptools, enigma-catalyst

I was trying to install catalyst using conda https://www.enigma.co/catalyst/install.html#troubleshooting-conda-install
but running into error.
I have installed 'Python 3.5, 3.6: Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools, which installs Visual C++ version 14.0. This is the recommended version' as recommended but not working. Please help

```
(catalyst) C:\Users\John>pip install enigma-catalyst matplotlib
Collecting enigma-catalyst
  Using cached enigma-catalyst-0.5.21.tar.gz (767 kB)
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (8.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=7.1.0 in e:\python_doc\anaconda3\envs\catalyst\lib\site-packages (from enigma-catalyst) (20.2.4)
Collecting setuptools==38.5.1
  Using cached setuptools-38.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (489 kB)
Collecting Logbook==0.12.5
  Using cached Logbook-0.12.5.tar.gz (166 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'E:\Python_Doc\anaconda3\envs\catalyst\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8i5dyoan\\logbook\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\John\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8i5dyoan\\logbook\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-go7ga4gn'
         cwd: C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8i5dyoan\logbook\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8i5dyoan\logbook\setup.py", line 57, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature'
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: `enigma-catalyst` lists very old requirements: `setuptools` 38.5.1 (current version is 50), `Logbook` 0.12.5 (current version is 1.5);  [`Logbook` 0.12.5](https://pypi.org/project/Logbook/0.12.5/) was released in 2016. Perhaps outdated incompatible requirements. BTW what is your current version of `setuptools`? Try to downgrade to 38.5.1 and retry installation.

Comment: omg thanks, i finally figured out. switch to setuptool to 45 works. But after installation, it would not work because of the requirement conflicts. Such as catalyst want numpy == 1.14 and some other package need a newer numpy.....headeach.... any suggestions of another backtest package?

Comment: "*any suggestions of another backtest package?*" Nop, sorry.